# Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist only on production mode in ReactJS application

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I'm building a chrome extension. My target is to sync data from my React web application to the Chrome extension. I used `externally_connectable` to send the data from my web app to the extension.

**Web app:**

```
window.chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
  CHROME_EXTENSIONS_ID,
  { credential: credential },
  () => {}
)
```

**Background script on extension**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function (
  request,
  sender,
  sendResponse
) {
  // receive the token and refresh token from commenty
  if (request.credential) {
    // do some stuff with request.credential
  }
});
```

My local app working on domain: `local.v2.context.app`, my development server working on `dev.context.app` and production server `context.app`

**manifest.json***

```
  "externally_connectable": {
    "ids": ["*"],
    "matches": ["https://*.context.app/*"],
    "accepts_tls_channel_id": false
  },
```

Everything works fine on my localhost with a local server with a custom domain. But when
I tried to run the extension with the development and the production server isn't working, get the error:

`Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

My web app was built with `create-react-app`. I think the error is somewhere in the way I set the `manifest.json` but I still can't figure out what the correct config is. Please can you give me some solution?

Thanks

Comment: Your local page is probably `http` not `https`.

Comment: hi  @wOxxOm my local page was trying to configure with SSL. However, I don't quite understand if SSL has any effect in this way

Comment: If your page is `http` then your `matches` is wrong.

Comment: Just my example @wOxxOm. Even, I paste exactly the website URL into the `matches` property. It's doesn't work

Comment: I guess you incorrectly declared the background script or it's a bug in Chrome.